# Odd Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a table in SQL Server that is performing very slowly and I have been trying different indexing options to try to speed it up to no avail.

I suspect all of the varchar(max) fields may be a source of the pain.

Here is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [SurveyData](
    [sdid] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [job_code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [job_title] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [job_level] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [job_description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [paytype] [char](1) NULL,
    [scope_fields] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [scope_values] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [data_fields] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [data_values] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [base_pay_fields] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [base_pay_values] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [var_pay_fields] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [var_pay_values] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [total_comp_fields] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [total_comp_values] [varchar](max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SurveyData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [sdid] ASC,
        [sid] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,         
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Doing any queries on this table causes the execution plan to use "Nested Loops (Inner Join) and a Key Lookup. Queries take at least 25 seconds to return data.

I filter data by sid, job_code, job_level, and scope_values. I do use a query with an inner join to retrieve data in a stored procedure, but I want to get the data flowing faster before I work on improving that.

Here is the query I'm using for testing:

```
SELECT [scope_values], [job_title], [job_code], [job_level], [paytype],              
    [job_description], [base_pay_fields], [base_pay_values],
    [var_pay_fields], [var_pay_values], [total_comp_fields], 
    [total_comp_values], [data_values], [sid]         
FROM [surveydata] WHERE [sid] = 176
```

Here is the link to the execution plan: [Execution Plan](http://home.jiggidiandesigns.com/temp/test-query.zip)

This query returns 55,455 rows, and takes approximately 27 seconds.

The varchars that are max probably don't need to be max, but there's no standard of how long the data in those fields will be (pipe delimited strings) which is why I went with max just to be safe. The slowdown is in management studio as well as in the application. I'm trying to get the queries more efficient so the delays will be reduced in the  application. I reduced all of the varchar(max) fields to varchar(255) and not much improvement and still the "nested loops" despite the fact that there is no inner join in the query.

The application will narrow the result down to 1 row, but that 1 row is taking forever (just like the 55k). I created a new table using the create script for the original table, then populated it with the original data. It no longer has the nested loops, but it now takes 2 minutes instead of 20ish seconds to complete in management studio.

Comment: Please be sure to add the query to the question (nobody wants to read a query in a comment) and also indicate what other indexes exist, how many rows in the table, and how many rows match your filter.

Comment: Takes approximately 27 seconds - to where? A results grid in Management Studio? Over what type of network? Have you determined what % of that time is spent transmitting and rendering the data? Maybe SQL Server isn't at fault at all - try using an application that discards results (like [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](https://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) - sorry, I work there), or to your app which is probably a lot more efficient about it, and try from the local machine or something much closer to the SQL Server network-wise.

Comment: Are stats updated and indexes defragmented? Also,is sid always the same? If it varies, then you are better off using OPTION RECOMPILE as well as OPTIMIZE FOR ADHOC.

Comment: So this looks like a "Bookmark lookup". What is essentially happening is that the non-clustered index doesn't contain all the data that the query wants, so its using the non-clustered index to get the key value so it can grab the data from the clustered index. Try including all the necessary columns in the non-clustered index